# Number appearing above two notes in tempo; how do I play/interpret this?

Tags: piano, tempo, beats

I'm trying to play Take me to church by Hozier on a program I made in assembly. It takes into account the pitch and the number of beats involved per note. In the piano music sheet I found for take me to church, on the part where tempo is specified, it says:

> "Slowly (quarter note) = 63 (two sixteenth notes with a beam = eighth note sixteenth note with a 3 bracket above)"

How do I interpret this based on the pitch and number of beats involved per note? Thank you.

Also (separate question from before), I'd like to ask how to interpret ties and slurs under the same criteria. Thank you.

[image: Music sheet in question]

Comment: - There are three quarter notes (or beats) in one 3/4 bar. And there are 63 of these beats per minute.
- This has nothing to do with pitch.
- What is your question about ties and slurs exactly? There are no ties and slurs in this example.

Comment: That's an eighth note beamed to a sixteenth, not a quarter

Comment: Which ties and slurs?

Answer (score 5):

'Slowly', backed up with an exact mm mark figure is about the tempo.

The notation in brackets that follows it means the 16th notes are to be played as triplets.

[image]

Comment: You should clarify for the newbies that the stuff in parentheses is entirely separate from the metronome specification of 63.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the metronome marking of "quarter note = 63" means 63 quarter notes per minute, or approximately one quarter note per second.